# Creating a shortcut to a network path in Python

Tags: python, win32com

I need to create a shortcut to a network drive in Python. We have a network drive that is mapped to various letters on different PCs (i.e.: I:\ or R:\) so I can't place a letter in front of the path because it various by user. Instead, I directly use the network path but when I try to run the following code, I get a com_error: 'Unable to save shortcut' and it tries to add a letter in front of it (ex. P:) Is there a quick fix around this issue?

```
import win32com.client

def main():
    CreateShortcut()

def CreateShortcut():
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut("\\xxxxxxx.xx.xx.xxx.com\\shared\\data\\Test_Results_Location.lnk")
    shortcut.Targetpath = "\\xxxxxxx.xx.xx.xxx.com\\shared\\data\\Machine\\Test_Results"
    #shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut("I:\\Test Results Location.lnk")             # This works fine
    #shortcut.Targetpath = "I:\\Machine\\Test_Results"
    shortcut.save()
    return shortcut

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Network paths usually start with two backslashes, i.e. `\\server\share`, so try four of them with escaping.

Comment: I’ll submit it as an answer then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network paths usually start with two backslashes, for example `\\server\share` to access the share called `share` on `server`. As such, when specifying the path to that share, you will have to use four backslashes if you want to escape it:

```
'\\\\xxxxxxx.xx.xx.xxx.com\\shared\\data\\Machine\\Test_Results'
```

Alternatively, you could also use raw paths, to make them look a bit less complicated as you don’t need to escape backslashes in them:

```
r'\\xxxxxxx.xx.xx.xxx.com\shared\data\Machine\Test_Results'
```